# How to fix a method/functionality in Flutter being executed so many times without loop?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a Flutter project which is a tricycle booking system that also uses Realtime Database in Firebase. If the ride status of the passenger has been accepted by the driver, an audio or notify sound will be executed then a modal popup/dialog will be displayed.

Upon trying, these two functionalities have been executed indefinitely and multiple times as long as the ride status of the passenger is accepted. How do I implement it once only and what is the reason behind it because I am not using any loop for this?

Here are the updated code for this method:

```
   saveRideRequestInformation() //Ride Request Code
  {
    //1. save the Ride Request Information

    referenceRideRequest = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child("All Ride Requests").push(); // Creates unique ID
    String? rideKey = referenceRideRequest!.key.toString();

    var originLocation = Provider.of<AppInfo>(context, listen: false).userPickUpLocation;
    var destinationLocation = Provider.of<AppInfo>(context, listen: false).userDropOffLocation;

    Map originLocationMap =
    {
      //key:value
      "latitude": originLocation!.locationLatitude.toString(),
      "longitude": originLocation!.locationLongitude.toString(),
    };

    Map destinationLocationMap =
    {
      //key:value
      "latitude": destinationLocation!.locationLatitude.toString(),
      "longitude": destinationLocation!.locationLongitude.toString(),
    };

    Map userInformationMap =
    {
      "origin": originLocationMap,
      "destination": destinationLocationMap,
      "time": DateTime.now().toString(),
      "username": userModelCurrentInfo!.username!,
      "email": userModelCurrentInfo!.email!,
      "id": userModelCurrentInfo!.id!,
      "requestId": rideKey,
      "originAddress": originLocation.locationName,
      "destinationAddress": destinationLocation.locationName,
      "driverId": "waiting",
      "notified" : "false",
    };

    referenceRideRequest!.set(userInformationMap);

    tripRideRequestInfoStreamSubscription = referenceRideRequest!.onValue.listen((eventSnap) async // getting updates in real time
    {
      if(eventSnap.snapshot.value == null)
        {
          return;
        }

      if ((eventSnap.snapshot.value as Map)["driverPlateNum"] != null) //!! GAWING CAR DETAILS/ PLATE NUMBER
      {
        setState(() {
          driverTricDetails = (eventSnap.snapshot.value as Map)["driverPlateNum"].toString();
        });
      }

      if ((eventSnap.snapshot.value as Map)["driverPhone"] != null) //!! GET PHONE NUMBER
          {
        setState(() {
          driverPhone = (eventSnap.snapshot.value as Map)["driverPhone"].toString();
        });
      }

      if ((eventSnap.snapshot.value as Map)["notified"] != null) //!! GET PHONE NUMBER
          {
        setState(() {
          notified = (eventSnap.snapshot.value as Map)["notified"].toString();
        });
      }

      if ((eventSnap.snapshot.value as Map)["driverName"] != null) //!! GET FNAME
          {
        setState(() {
          driverName = (eventSnap.snapshot.value as Map)["driverName"].toString();
        });
      }

      if((eventSnap.snapshot.value as Map)["status"] != null)
      {
        setState(() {
          userRideRequestStatus = (eventSnap.snapshot.value as Map)["status"].toString();
        });
      }

      if((eventSnap.snapshot.value as Map)["driverLocation"] != null)
      {
        double driverCurrentPositionLat = double.parse((eventSnap.snapshot.value as Map)["driverLocation"]["latitude"].toString());
        double driverCurrentPositionLng = double.parse((eventSnap.snapshot.value as Map)["driverLocation"]["longitude"].toString());

        LatLng driverCurrentPositionLatLng = LatLng(driverCurrentPositionLat, driverCurrentPositionLng);

        if(userRideRequestStatus != null)
        {
          isVisible= !isVisible;
          showUIForAssignedDriverInfo();

          //when status = accepted
          if(userRideRequestStatus == "accepted" && notified == "false") {
            FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref()
                .child("All Ride Requests")
                .child(rideKey)
                .child("notified")
                .set("true");

            passengerIsOfflineNow();
            assignedDriverModal();

            updateArrivalTimeToUserPickupLocation(driverCurrentPositionLatLng);
          }

          //when status = arrived
          if(userRideRequestStatus == "arrived")
          {
            setState(() {
              driverRideStatus = "Your driver has arrived.";
            });
          }

          //when status = onTrip
          if(userRideRequestStatus == "onTrip")
          {
            updateReachingTimeToUserDropOffLocation(driverCurrentPositionLatLng);
          }

          //when status = ended
          if(userRideRequestStatus == "ended")
          {
            if((eventSnap.snapshot.value as Map)["fareAmount"] != null)
            {
              double fareAmount = double.parse((eventSnap.snapshot.value as Map)["fareAmount"].toString());

              var response = await showDialog(
                context: context,
                barrierDismissible: false,
                builder: (BuildContext c) => PayFareAmountDialog(
                  fareAmount: fareAmount,
                ),
              );

              if(response == "cashPayed")
              {
                //user can rate the driver
                if((eventSnap.snapshot.value as Map)["driverId"] != null)
                {
                  String assignedDriverId = (eventSnap.snapshot.value as Map)["driverId"].toString();

                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c)=> RateDriverScreen(
                    assignedDriverId: assignedDriverId,
                  )));

                  referenceRideRequest!.onDisconnect();
                  tripRideRequestInfoStreamSubscription!.cancel();
                }
              }
            }
          }
      }
    }
    });

    onlineNearbyAvailableDriversList = GeoFireAssistant.activeNearbyAvailableDriversList;
    //searchNearestOnlineDrivers();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because of the snapshot listener that runs when the driver location updates. As the driver location updates, it loops through everything in your if statement. This specifically:

```
if((eventSnap.snapshot.value as Map)["driverLocation"] != null)
      {
        double driverCurrentPositionLat = double.parse((eventSnap.snapshot.value as Map)["driverLocation"]["latitude"].toString());
        double driverCurrentPositionLng = double.parse((eventSnap.snapshot.value as Map)["driverLocation"]["longitude"].toString());

        LatLng driverCurrentPositionLatLng = LatLng(driverCurrentPositionLat, driverCurrentPositionLng);

        if(userRideRequestStatus != null)
        {
          isVisible= !isVisible;
          showUIForAssignedDriverInfo();

          //when status = accepted. !! this is my concern !!
          if(userRideRequestStatus == "accepted")
...
```

What you could consider doing is adding a flag in the `eventSnap.snapshot.value` to say something along the lines of notified. And then after you run the `if(userRideRequestStatus == "accepted")` statement, flip the `notified` value to `true`. This would then change your accepted if statement from `if(userRideRequestStatus == "accepted")` to `if(userRideRequestStatus == "accepted" && !driverNotified)`.

Comment: what do you mean by adding a flag?

Comment: Can you give an example, I am confused. :( I only need to display the dialog when the status is accepted, I can't think of any other conditions...

Comment: I am saying you can add a value to your RTDB that you store as false until you send your driver a notification and then flip that flag to true so your code knows that you have already notified the driver. This if value keeps getting run `if((eventSnap.snapshot.value as Map)["driverLocation"] != null)` and then runs the `if(userRideRequestStatus == "accepted")` since its contained within it.

Comment: I get the idea now but can you give an example of codes on how could I implement it?

Comment: hey, I have tried doing your comment and it somehow fixed my problem, but it still iterates 5 times tho, why? please help :(

Comment: There is probably a queue of driver location updates between when you updated the value and when you played the noise. You could maybe swap a server value of `driverNotified` for a local one.

Comment: I have updated the question with the code you taught me, can you check it please and know how will I correct it so that it won't iterate anymore? Also, I have noticed that the sound is just playing two times but the dialog is overlapping itself like 5 times..

Comment: What do you mean by "swap a server value of driverNotified for a local one"?

Comment: Create a local variable called driverNotified rather than storing it in RTDB

Comment: okay... same concept right, but store it in a local variable and then?

Comment: Yup same concept. Since you are doing it locally, you don't have to wait for the stream to update with the new value. So since there is probably 5 driver location updates between you notifying the driver (and setting driverNotified in the DB), you would need to wait for the stream to catch up to that new driverNotified value. If you set it locally, it would catch it prior to the stream catching up.